# Recurrence Relation, Compound Annually

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, computer-science

If I invest $\$2000$/yr in a tax sheltered annuity at $7\%$, where $A_n$ is the amount at $n$ years... what is the recurrence relation? I know my initial condition $A_0$ is $2000$. And for some reason the answer I got is $A_n = (1.12)^2 \cdot A_0$.

Any help would be appreciated, I’m not sure where I went wrong!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: This seems to be a geometric sum.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the $n$th year, you invest $\$2000$ and earn $7\%$ interest on what you earned the previous year.  Hence,
$$A_n = \$2000 + 0.07A_{n - 1}, n \geq 1$$
which is the recurrence relation.  The initial value in your account is $A_0 = \$2000$.

Let's examine what happens during the first few years. 
\begin{align*}
A_0 & = \$2000\\
A_1 & = \$2000 + 0.07A_0\\
    & = \$2000 + 0.07 \cdot \$2000\\
    & = \$2000(1 + 0.07)\\
A_2 & = \$2000 + 0.07A_1\\
    & = \$2000 + 0.07[\$2000(1 + 0.07)]\\
    & = \$2000 + 0.07 \cdot \$2000 + 0.07^2 \cdot \$2000\\
    & = \$2000(1 + 0.07 + 0.07^2)\\
A_3 & = \$2000 + 0.07A_2\\
    & = \$2000 + 0.07[\$2000(1 + 0.07 + 0.07^2)]\\
    & = \$2000 + 0.07 \cdot \$2000 + 0.07^2 \cdot \$2000 + 0.07^3 \cdot \$2000\\
    & = \$2000(1 + 0.07 + 0.07^2 + 0.07^3)
\end{align*}
which suggests that 
$$A_n = \$2000(1 + 0.07 + 0.07^2 + 0.07^3 + \cdots + 0.07^n) = \$2000\sum_{k = 0}^{n} 0.07^k$$
which you can prove by induction.

As for finding an explicit formula, you can use the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) formula 
$$A_n = a(1 + r + r^2 + \cdots + r^n) = a\frac{1 - r^{n + 1}}{1 - r}, r \neq 1$$
with $a = \$2000$ and $r = 0.07$.